# Microsoft Access cannot create primary key

Tags: ms-access

I'm very new to databases. I have a project that I'm supposed to do which basically is restoring this database that's a huge mess. Bad naming conventions, not normalized and so on.

I try to assign a PK to a field but I cant because access throws me an error saying that the values are duplicates.

I am supposed to put this table into 1NF and then move on from there to 3NF.

A field in this table is called "WarehouseID" and "CustomerID"

The problem is the project wants me to keep some data the same such as the warehouseID and customerID, and the warehouseID is used multiple times more than once.

Example:

**WarehouseID**

WH1

WH1

WH2

WH2

WH2

**CustomerID**

1

2

3

3

4

5

5

The table is already in 1NF but I cannot assign a PK to the field "WarehouseID" because it has multiple values.

Even when I try to make this table 2NF I cannot make the PK in the seperate tables because I will still get the following result

**WarehouseID**

3

3

4

4

5

5

8

I am not too sure what to do.

Comment: Need to create a new table where each warehouse is a unique record. Your original table can be source for that dataset. `SELECT DISTINCT WarehouseID, WarehouseName FROM tablename;` This will be the master list for warehouse info and the original table will be a dependent table. Do the same for customer info. Of course this assumes the warehouse and customer names are consistent for each unique ID.

Comment: Not too sure what WarehouseName is supposed to be. The current table doesn't have a "WarehouseName" just the warehouse ID?

Comment: Don't know your data structure, it was just an example. Perhaps instead of name there would be address info. Include whatever fields you want as long as the records will still be DISTINCT (unique) for each ID.

Answer (score 0):

Well keep in mind that for a given table, a PK will only EVER occur one time.

Each table should have a PK and they will not be used as a PK in any other table.

So, you might have a table called Warehouse.

It can have a PK of WarehoueID

And you might have a table called Customer, and it can have a PK called CustomerID.

Next up:
If you ALWAYS assign one customer to a given warehouse, then simply add a column to customer table called warehouseID. However this column is NOT a PK. It is a “plane jane” long number column. This column will most certainly allow duplicates.

The only real issue you here is can a customer have or use more than one warehouse?

Can you assign more than one warehouse to a given customer?

Well, then you simply need to create a table or “list” of warehouses that a customer can use.

If above is the case, then you need a table called:

CustomerListOfWareHouses.

The above table would simply be a “list” of warehouses that a given customer has in use. If this is what you want, then you NOT need the warehouseID at all in the customer table.

You have

```
tblCustomes
   --->tblCustomerListOfWareHouses
```

So tblcustomerListOfWareHouses would be what we call a child table.

In that table, you would have a PK (ListOfWareHousesID), and then you can set who this record belongs to (customerID), and then set the warehouse they are using (WareHouseID).

So that “list” of warehouses would look like:

```
ListOfWareHousesID   (PK)
CustomerID           (plane jane long number colum)
WarehouseID          (plane jane long number colum)
Date of Enter       (date column, when created)
Who Authorized       (person that approved use of warehouse).
“and perhaps a few ore columns if  you want or need).
```

And then the 3rd table of warehouses. In this setup, you don’t actually EVER attach a warehouse to a given customer, but simply have a table that “lists out” the warehouses the customer has in use.

This would assume that each customer can use and have “many” warehouse.

So you never really attach a warehouse to a customer. All you really do is “list out” in a table the warehouses the customer has in use (tblCustomerListOfWareHouses).

So what this means is that the customer table and the warehouse table are NEVER attached to each other, and there is not any enforced relationship between customers and warehouses.

You data model will “allow” you to attach “many” warehouses to one customer, but in actual fact all you really do is “list out” the warehouses the customer has by adding records to the “list of warehouses” the customer has in use (tblCustoerListOfWareHouses).

Of course if a customer can ONLY use and have one warehouse? Well then just add a column to table customers called WareHouseID and simply enter the “id” value into that one customer to attach that customer to the one warehouse. (so  you would not need the “list of warehouses” because they are only allowed to use one warehouse).

As noted, you only need the “list of” warehouses if a customer can use and have more than one warehouse.

So each warehouse record will have a PK, and so will each customer. But nothing suggests any duplicates at this point in time.

If a customer only can use one warehouse, then add that simple column to customer table that holds the warehouse. And that is a plane Jane column – many customers can use the same warehouse, and that column will most certainly allow duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Add an autonumber field - then designate it as the PK.

Obviously any field with duplicates cannot be the PK field - so you'll want to deal with that in some way.  One idea would to create a new table with a DISTINCT list of that field.  And then make this new table the master table and the existing table the child table.  Just an off the cuff idea - and may not be suitable in your situation.

I advise that all active transaction table use PK fields of autonumber fields only - although not everyone agrees with this design philosophy.  Only static list tables i.e. List of States are suitable for non autonumber PK fields.